# Android adapter's edittext using addchangelistener

Tags: android, android-edittext

Basically after trying for the whole day, i still can't seem to get the listener right. What i am trying to do here is to use the listener to capture some information from Edittext; achieved. But with the code as attached, i can't seem to capture the right information. Regardless of row, whenever Edittext is changed, only the first row will get "changed".

Please kindly advise.

```
public class ModuleAdapterCom extends ArrayAdapter<moduleDetails> {


Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<moduleDetails> data = new ArrayList<moduleDetails>();


public ModuleAdapterCom(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<moduleDetails> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    UserHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new UserHolder();
        holder.comName = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.comNameEditText);
        holder.weightage = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.weightageEditText2);
        holder.minTargetEditText = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.minTargetEditText);
        holder.watcher = new myWatcher();
        holder.achieved = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.achieved);
        holder.achieved.addTextChangedListener(holder.watcher);
        holder.watcher.setActive(false);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    moduleDetails selected = data.get(position);
    holder.comName.setText(selected.getName());
    holder.weightage.setText(""+selected.getComponentPercent());
    holder.minTargetEditText.setText(""+ selected.getMinPercent());

    if (data.get(position).getAchievePercent() == null){holder.watcher.setActive(true);}
    else {
        holder.watcher.setActive(false);
        holder.achieved.setText(""+selected.getAchievePercent());
        holder.watcher.setActive(true);
      /*  System.out.println("Setting: " + data.get(position).getName()+ " to: "+
                data.get(position).getAchievePercent());

     System.out.println("Setting: " + data.get(1).getName()+ " to: "+
              data.get(1).getAchievePercent()); */
        ;}

    return row;

}

static class UserHolder {
    EditText comName;
    EditText weightage;
    EditText minTargetEditText;
    EditText achieved;
    myWatcher watcher;

}

class myWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private int mPosition;
    private boolean mActive;

    void setPosition(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }

    void setActive(boolean active) {
        mActive = active;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (mActive) {

            data.get(mPosition).setAchievePercent(Double.parseDouble(s.toString()));
            System.out.println("managed to change "+ data.get(mPosition).getName()+"  "+
                    data.get(mPosition).getAchievePercent().toString());



        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
```

that way you are telling the adapter that current data in the adapter is updated so reflect the changes in the listview.

Comment: kudos for the reply. but after adding that, only the corresponding row  of the edittext remained empty, while the rest of the row's edit text got updated to the new vale.

Comment: you also need to make change in your data value then only it will be reflected in your view. like updating the value of the data at that position and then calling notifyDataSetChanged()